# edit a text file lines by using script in linux

Tags: bash, edit

I have a file like this below,

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
export basename=z-4-1_
```

in file "1.bash" I would like to keep as is but in file "2.bash" I would like to change in to z-4-2_ and in file "3.bash" I would like to change in to z-4-3_, and on until I get to 15.

how would like tackle this problem? by using script to modify these numbers in different files.

Answer (score 2):

This script should do it for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..15}
do
    touch file$i.bash
    echo '#!/bin/bash' >> file$i.bash
    echo 'i=1' >> file$i.bash
    echo 'export basename=z-4-'$i'_' >> file$i.bash
done
```

Comment: so this will make new files right? I was looking for just editing original files that I had.

Comment: yeah that makes new ones. if you already have them all do a `rm file*.bash` to delete them all first. The script will then recreate them all

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat shorter:

```
for i in {1..15}
do
  echo -e "#!/bin/bash\ni=1\nexport basename=z-4-${i}_" > $i.bash
done
```